# docker-compose for Detached mode

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have following docker command to run container

```
docker run -d --name test -v /etc/hadoop/conf:/etc/hadoop/conf -v /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hdinsight_common:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hdinsight_common -v /etc/hive/conf/:/etc/hive/conf/ -v /etc/tez/conf/:/etc/tez/conf/ -v /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/sqoop/lib/:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/sqoop/lib/ -i -t hdinsight /bin/bash
```

This was to complicated so I was trying to create docker-compose file like this

```
version: '2'
services:
  hdinsight:
    image: hdinsight
    container_name: ABC
    volumes:
     - /etc/hadoop/conf:/etc/hadoop/conf
     - /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hdinsight_common:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hdinsight_common
     - /etc/hive/conf/:/etc/hive/conf/
     - /etc/tez/conf/:/etc/tez/conf/
     - /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/sqoop/lib/:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/sqoop/lib/
    entrypoint:
     - bash
    labels:
     - "HDInsight client VM"
```

But I am not sure where to pass `-d`, `-i` & `-t` flages from my original docker run command

I was running docker-compose like this

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run hdinsight
```

can anyone point me to right direction here ?

UPDATE after first answer

I tried to run `docker-compose up -d`

```
root@abc-docker:~/ubuntu# docker-compose up -d
Creating ABC
root@sbd-docker:~/ubuntu# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
ffa4c359abf7        hdinsight           "/bin/bash"         5 seconds ago       Exited (0) 5 seconds ago                       ABC
root@sbd-docker:~/ubuntu#
```

Dont know why its in `Exited` status

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: Your provided `entrypoint` executes `bash`, `bash` requries an interactive session to run. Executing `docker-compose up -d` starts the container non-interactive, thus `bash` immediately exits. If you want an interactive session, execute `docker-compose run hdinsight`.

Comment: Pit is right. Sorry, my answer did not cater for the fact that you were trying to run interactively. Up doesn't do that.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You should scour the Compose file [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).

Most *docker run* commands have a compose equivalent, and they should all be listed there.

The background flag -d goes after *run* or *up*.

The tty flag -t and interactive flag -i are not required as docker-compose run [does this by default](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/). You can add tty to individual containers in the compose file with -t, but you cannot use interactive mode since you may start multiple containers at once and you can't interact with them all.

In regard to your situation the command you're using should be working. If you add -d after the run command it will run in the background. But I recommend using *up* instead of *run*, as it will simply start all containers in the file rather than you having to specify hdinsight.

Comment: I'm struggling with docker-compose as well, it seems that I can use `docker-compose run` to run something interactively with a tty, and it works fine, but if I start it detached with -d, no tty is created. For comparison, `docker run -dti image /bin/bash` does create a tty, and I can attach later. I did specify `tty: true` in the docker-compose.yaml file. So, it seems this answer is not valid when using -d, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're right. When you docker-compose run a container with -d it doesn't create a tty, doesn't keep bash running, and thus the container stops.
Strange that there'd be such a discrepancy between such similar commands.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong.  See other answers by Ortomala and Anand.  The correct answer is tty:true and stdin_open: true

Answer (score 38):

As said by Anand Suthar, you have to use `tty: true` and `stdin_open: true`. Here is a minimal example:

```
version: "3"
services:
  alpine1:
    image: alpine
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
```

Start with:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Attach to a container with:

```
docker attach 268bcfb650fb
```

and detach with `^P^Q`.

Answer (score 19):

From the Document

```
Usage: up [options] [--scale SERVICE=NUM...] [SERVICE...]

Options:
    -d, --detach               Detached mode: Run containers in the background,
                               print new container names. Incompatible with
                               --abort-on-container-exit.
```

[docker-compose up doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)

the command should be

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: I must be using some strange version (1.24.0, build 0aa5906) of docker-compose since the "-d" option is not present and `docker-compose -d up` simply does nothing

Comment: @andrej I think the -d must place behind 'up', as options are placed at last

Answer (score 10):

Today I am facing the same issue and below is how I manage.

> I add **tty: true** kay value **&** **stdin_open: true** key value in 'docker-compose.yml' file as below and I am sure it will run in detach mode and one can also interact with console.

```
version: '2'
services:
hdinsight:
image: hdinsight
container_name: ABC
volumes:
 - /etc/hadoop/conf:/etc/hadoop/conf
 - /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hdinsight_common:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hdinsight_common
 - /etc/hive/conf/:/etc/hive/conf/
 - /etc/tez/conf/:/etc/tez/conf/
 - /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/sqoop/lib/:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/sqoop/lib/
entrypoint:
 - bash
labels:
 - "HDInsight client VM"
tty: true
stdin_open: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to attach to an existing container, this is now much easier using [profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) introduced in [1.28.0](https://docs.docker.com/compose/release-notes/#1280).

Here's a basic example showing a normal service alongside a CLI container:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=INSECURE
    volumes:
      - mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  cli:
    image: node:16
    user: node
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:INSECURE@db/prisma
    working_dir: "/app"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: bash
    profiles:
      - cli

volumes:
  mariadb:
```

After running `docker-compose up -d`, `docker-compose run cli` will give you a bash shell inside of the container.

For more complex apps, consider overriding the entrypoint. In the nodejs, world, if you set it to `npx`, and leave command undefined, you can then run arbitrary npx commands with `docker-compose run npx ...`. And for common tasks that are always non-interactive, you can drop the `std_open` and `tty` lines while leaving the profile set.