# unknown shorthand flag: 'd' in -d docker compose

Tags: docker-compose

I am working with a docker compose. when a trying to run docker compose in background, but it shows error **unknown shorthand flag: 'd' in -d**

I am tried in this way

```
docker compose -d up
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

networks:
  loki:

services:
  loki:
    image: grafana/loki:2.5.0
    # volumes:
    #   - ./loki:/loki
    ports:
      - 3100:3100
    networks:
      - loki
  
  promtail:
    image: grafana/promtail
    volumes:
      - ./promtail:/etc/promtail
      - /var/log/nginx/:/var/log/nginx/
    command: -config.file=/etc/promtail/promtail-config.yml
    ports:
      - 9080:9080
    networks:
      - loki
  
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - loki
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker-compose for Detached mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086453/docker-compose-for-detached-mode)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`-d` is an option of subcommand `up`.
if you run `docker compose up --help` you will have more information.

To solve the problem run `docker compose up -d`

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer is the right answer for the question asker, and anyone else putting the `-d` in the wrong place.  But this is the top hit for the error message, and I'm sure I'm not the only one getting this error after running:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

The accepted answer telling me to run exactly what I ran was pretty confusing.  I finally worked out that:

1. `docker-compose` is a separate package from `docker`, at least on Arch Linux, and likely elsewhere, and
2. If `docker-compose` isn't installed, Docker thinks this makes sense:

   ```
   $ docker compose up -d
   unknown shorthand flag: 'd' in -d
   ```

I think it wold be infinitely more sensible to respond with:

```
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
```

Which is what it says if you don't use `-d` while not having `docker-compose` installed.  I've now installed `docker-compose` and things are working, but I thought it was worth the time to hopefully save someone else some trouble if they end up here because they have `docker` but not `docker-compose`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me, if you are on Arch a simple `sudo pacman -S docker-compose` fixes the issue

Comment: Check if docker compose plugin is installed with this command: `docker compose version` If not, install docker-compose plugin. For linux apt: `sudo apt install docker-compose-plugin`

Answer (score 6):

We were using a legacy version of Docker for compatibility purposes; in the older versions it's `docker-compose` not `docker compose`. Changing it to be hyphenated resolved this error.